# Symfony function search wih query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, query-builder

I would like to create a function to search for a movie through the query builder

```
I have a table Movie:

     1. Id
     2. Titre
     3. Content
```

And i have class **MovieRepository** :

```
class MovieRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myFindAll()
        {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        }


    public function getSearchMovies($movie){


            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
                            ->where('m.title LIKE :title')
                                ->setParameter('title', '%' . $movie->getTitle() . '%')
                                    ->orderBy('m.title', 'DESC')
                                        ->getQuery();


    }   
}
```

Also i have **MovieController** :

```
public function indexAction()
        {
            $movie = new Movie;
            $form = $this->createForm(new SearchMovieType(), $movie);

            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
                $form->bind($request);
                $movies = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                            ->getRepository('AreaDownloadBundle:Movie')
                                ->getSearchUsers($movie);

                return $this->render('AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),array('movies' => $movies)));
            } else {

                $movies = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getManager()
                                ->getRepository('AreaDownloadBundle:Movie')
                                    ->myFindAll();

                return $this->render('AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView(), 'movies' => $movies));
            }
        }
```

**SearchMovieType** :

```
class SearchMovieType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('title','text', array('required' => false, ))
                ;
    }
```

And i have **index.hml.twig**, which can display movies with a search bar :

```
{% extends "::template.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
<form action="{{ path('area_download_index') }}"  method="post">

    <div id="bar">          
        {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Chercher"> 
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
</form> 

    {% for movie in movies %}
       {{ movie.title }}
       {{ movie.content }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

when I  seized a title of a movie he sends me this error

**Variable "movies" does not exist in AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig at line 12**

Comment: return $this->render('AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),array('movies' => $movies)));
Maybe there have an error. 
Try like this

return $this->render('AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'movies' => $movies));

Comment: @Akim yeah, i was about to say the same thing

Comment: Hi there Martin. If my answer is the one that solved the problem, can you click the 'checkmark' besides the answer to indicate that? This is helpful when people are searching for the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting it as a comment, it should have been posted as an answer in the correct formatting; like so:

```
return $this->render(
    'AreaDownloadBundle:Download:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'movies' => $movies
    )
);
```

This definitely should fix the problem!